# How to avoid white spaces when crossing 'pen tool' lines in Inkscape?

Tags: vector, inkscape

I am on Ubuntu and trying to learn Inkscape. When I draw a line with the 'pen tool', if a line self-intersects there is a white space in the intersection. How do I avoid that? Is there some setting for it?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems an issue with the [Calligraphy Tool](http://inkscape.org/doc/calligraphy/tutorial-calligraphy.html), that creates closed paths.

By default, closed path intersections aren't filled (fill-rule: evenodd), and you must select a different rule (fill-rule: nonzero) in *Fill and Stroke* toolbar (in *Fill* tab). The behavior of the fill changes consequently:

[image: Fill rules and calligraphy tool]